# Loguin API AOL Token

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, url

Estoy buscando loguearme un un sitio a traves de Python.

No se como hacerlo ya que es a traves de su API, Dejo aca la informacion que me proporciona la API para loguearme. Es realmente necesario que lo haga a traves de python. Me he logueado a traves de otras APIs pero con esta se me hace imposible ya que no se por donde arrancar. 
Si yo estoy logueado a traves del Browser, en la terminal coloco:

```
curl 'https://onevideo.aol.com/sessions/session_info?oauth=fb7f6a10-df16-418e-846b-4a00c2618e'
```

y me devuelve

```
// https://onevideo.aol.com/sessions/session_info?oauth=fb7f6a10-df16-418e-846b-4a00c2618e
{
  "result": {
    "code": "OK",
    "msg": ""
  },
  "id": 34736,
  "first_name": "juan",
  "last_name": "perez",
  "email": "juan@perez",
  "user_name": "juanoperez",
  "org_id": 11776,
  "one_source": "",
  "is_super": 0,
  "duplicate_email_status": "",
  "session_id": "fb7f6a10-df16-418e-846b-4a00c2618e"
```

Cabe destacar que esa url que introduzco en la terminal la obtuve a traves de inspect una vez logueado!

```
Obtain an access token

In order to make API calls, an access token is required. Obtaining the token is a two step process:

Generate JsonWebToken (JWT).
Use the generated JWT to get the OAuth2 token.
Note: Both tokens above have an expiration time and will need to be regenerated periodically (or upon a rejection because of inactive token from any of the API calls).

How do I generate a JWT ?

A JWT consists of three parts, separated by dots (.), which are:

Header
Payload
Signature
A typical JWT looks like this:

<base64url-encoded header>.<base64url-encoded payload>.<base64url-encoded signature>
Header

The header typically consists of two parts: the type of the token, which is JWT, and the hashing algorithm such as HMAC SHA256 or RSA.

Example:

1
{ "alg": "HS256", "typ": "JWT”}
Base64Url encoded of this JSON forms the first part of the JWT.

Payload

The second part of the token is the payload, which contains the claims. Claims are statements about an entity (typically, the user) and additional metadata.

Example:

1
{
2
"aud": "https://{b2b.host}/identity/oauth2/access_token?realm=aolcorporate/aolexternals",
3
"iss": "{client_id}",
4
"sub": "{client_id}",
5
"exp": {expiry time in seconds},
6
"iat": {issued time in seconds},
7
"jti": "{UUID}"
8
}
client_id = OAuth2 Client ID
UUID: Unique Id
issued time in seconds: Current time in seconds.
expiry time in seconds: Future time (ex: +10 mins) in seconds. Make sure this not too far into the future. More than 24 hours would be rejected. 10 mins in the future is a typical value.
UAT B2B host: id-uat2.corp.aol.com
Prod B2B host: id.corp.aol.com
Note: exp/iat are Date objects, not strings.

Base64Url encoded of this JSON forms the second part of the JWT.

Signature

To create the signature part, you have to take the encoded header, the encoded payload, a secret, the algorithm specified in the header, and sign that.

For example if you want to use the HMAC SHA256 algorithm, the signature will be created as follows:

HMACSHA256(base64UrlEncode(header) + "." + base64UrlEncode(payload),secret)
secret = OAuth2 Client Secret
The signature is used to verify that the sender of the JWT is who it says it is and to ensure that the message wasn't changed in the request flow.

Putting it all together

The output is three Base64Url encoded strings separated by dots that can be easily passed in HTML and HTTP environments. A sample JWT token looks something like this (dots highlighted in red):

ew0KICAiYWxnIjogIkhTMjU2IiwNCiAgICJ0eXAiOiAiSldUIg0KfQ.ew0KICAiYXVkIjogIntwcm90b2NvbH06Ly97YjJiLmhvc3R9L2lkZW50aXR5L29hdX
RoMi9hY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4/cmVhbG09PHlvdXItcmVhbG0+IiwNCiAgImlzcyI6ICJ7Y2xpZW50X2lkfSIsDQogICJzdWIiOiAie2NsaWVudF9pZH0iLA0KICA
iZXhwIjog4oCce2V4cGlyeSB0aW1lIGluIHNlY29uZHN94oCdLA0KICAiaWF0Ijog4oCce2lzc3VlZCB0aW1lIGluIHNlY29uZHN94oCdDQp9DQo.uKqU9dTB
6gKwG6jQCuXYAiMNdfNRw98Hw_IWuA5MaMo
There are many libraries for different development languages and environments that can be used to create the JWT. Below is a Java example, using jose4j:

01
public static String generateJsonWebToken(final String clientId, final String secret,
02
final String audience) throws OCAuthException {
03

04
   JwtClaims claims = new JwtClaims();
05
   claims.setIssuedAt(NumericDate.now());
06
   claims.setExpirationTimeMinutesInTheFuture(1); -- Expiration time of the JWT
07
   claims.setSubject(clientId);
08
   claims.setIssuer(clientId);
09
   claims.setAudience(audience);
10
   claims.setGeneratedJwtId();
11

12
   try {
13
       Key key = new HmacKey(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"));
14

15
       JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();
16
       jws.setPayload(claims.toJson());
17
       jws.setAlgorithmHeaderValue(AlgorithmIdentifiers.HMAC_SHA256);
18
       jws.setKey(key);
19
       jws.setDoKeyValidation(false);
20

21
       return jws.getCompactSerialization();
22

23
   } catch (Exception e) {
24
       throw new OCAuthException("JWT Generation failed", e);
25
   }
26
}
For JWT generation in other programming languages, see the Generating the JWT Using Different Languages.

Generating an OAuth2 Token

Once a valid JWT is obtained, an OAuth2 token can be generated by issuing the following request:

Endpoint

POST https://<b2b.host>/identity/oauth2/access_token
Request body

Request body should include the arguments listed below and should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded:

Field Name  Required/Optional   Value
grant_type  Required    MUST be 'client_credentials'
client_assertion_type   Required    MUST be 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer'
client_assertion    Required    JWT Token value (varies for each client request)
scope   Required    one
realm   Required    aolcorporate/aolexternals
Sample request

POST /identity/oauth2/access_token  HTTP/1.1
     Host: https://id.corp.aol.com
     Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
     Accept: application/json

grant_type=client_credentials&scope=one&realm=aolcorporate/aolexternals&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:
client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&client_assertion=<JWT Token>
Sample response

Format: json Status: 200 Headers: Content-Type: application/json
{
 "access_token": "3f94eb47-a295-4977-a375-e27bea5c828b",
 "scope": "one",
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": 599
}
Using the OAuth2 token

Use the generated OAuth2 token in the Authorization HTTP header (Bearer <OAuth2 Token>) while communicating with AOL API’s.

For example: “Authorization: Bearer 3f94eb47-a295-4977-a375-e27bea5c828b”

Returning the OAuth2 token

Finally, you'll need to send the token back when you make the API call.  Here is an example of how you do it in PHP:

<?php

$token = '';
$orgId = '';

if ($token & $orgId) {
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    // This is the same API call as before I've left this here as a place holder.
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://onevideo.aol.com/reporting/run_report?org_id='.$orgId.'&keys=date&metrics=ad_impressions&start_date=1486972800&end_date=1487059200&currency_id=150&timezone=228&report_type=0&is_date_international_format=0',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      'Accept: application/json',
      'Authorization: Bearer '.$token
    )    ));

    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    // Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);

    echo $resp;
}else{
  echo 'Need To Send Token';
}


?>
Refreshing the OAuth2 token

The OAuth2 token expires after a specified number of seconds (expires_in attribute of the access token response) from the time the response was generated. The API consumer needs to refresh the token after the expiration time is elapsed or upon rejection because of an inactive hostoken from any API call.

Security considerations

If using a shared secret (HS256) to sign the JWT, it is critical that:

The secret is protected and NEVER exposed to the browser.
All interactions MUST be protected by TLS.
If the credentials are compromised at any point, it is very important to notify AOL immediately so that the compromised credentials are revoked and new credentials are issued.

It is crucial to share the client credentials securely with the external parties. Options include using PGP to encrypt the credentials or using encrypted mails.
```

Comment: lo solucionaste? tengo el mismo problema :(

Answer (score 1):

Yo tambien tuve que trabajar con este API.

Aqui copio el metodo para que generes el jwt token

```
import uuid
import jwt
import datetime


def get_jwt_token(client_id, secret):
    millis = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    plus10min = millis + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)

    payload = {
        'aud': "https://id.corp.aol.com/identity/oauth2/access_token?realm=aolcorporate/aolexternals",
        'iss': client_id,
        'sub': client_id,
        'iat': millis,
        'exp': plus10min,
        'jti': str(uuid.uuid4())
    }

    encoded = jwt.encode(payload, secret, algorithm='HS256')
    return encoded.decode('utf-8')
```

Aqui la solucion completa en:

https://gist.github.com/rmondragon/198fa3e47186f09dd86f114d128eee64
https://gitlab.com/snippets/1747494

Funciona :)

Suerte, R6

Comment: Hola Rolando, las respuestas que son básicamente enlaces se consideran de baja calidad porque si el enlace se rompe (algo relativamente común), entonces dejan de tener sentido. Deberías copiar las partes claves de la página enlazada en la propia respuesta (manteniendo el enlace como referencia). Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro, listo agregue la parte que resuelve la consulta.